# Columns not "stacking"

Tags: html, css

Sorry for maybe a bad title but like many of my problems, they are hard to describe as titles.

To demonstrate my problem I have created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7YTd/4/

What I want is to have every div with the class "friend_left" to float to the left side like a list and every div with the class "friend_right" to float to the right.
It works perfectly with 2 friends but when I add 3 or more they start to fill the middle aswell like the JSFiddle shows.

How do I make it to stay left/right no matter what?

In order to post JSFiddle-links I have to provide some code, here is my CSS:

```
#profile_friends {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -10px;
background: rgb(240,240,240);
border: 2px solid #555;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 100%;
}
#friendlist {
overflow: auto;
}
.friend_left {
float: left;
width: 250px;
}

.friend_right {
float: right;
width: 250px;
}

.friend img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 8px;
}

.friend ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: 35px;
}

#profile_friends h4 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: rgb(110,110,110);
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
}

#profile_friends hr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: dont make float:right and lefts

Comment: Personally I'd go for two parent divs, one floated left and one right and then put each of the friends in either the left or right div. If you want two columns make two columns. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to add `clear:left` to your `.friend_left` class, and `clear:right` to your `.friend_right` class:

```
.friend_left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    clear:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b7YTd/9/)**

Comment: This looks good but should there be warnings about if some of the friend boxes are taller than others? It won't quite stack as expected necessarily will it (eg if a left is too big it will move the corresponding right down too). See http://jsfiddle.net/uk4ct/ for what I mean.

Comment: @Chris - that's a rule of floats ("The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document."). The only way around that would be to rearrange the HTML or use JavaScript, something like Masonry, so move things around.

Comment: Yup. I totally agree. But I think mentioning possible side effects (may not be an issue if they are all fixxed height) is worth while. But yes, this is the best lightweight solution, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a grid framework like [SimpleGrid](http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/). It will make sure that everything is in order and you don't need to bother with the detail work.

Comment: Like many other CSS frameworks, SimpleGrid also uses floats! Appreciate the reference.

Comment: I think it's probably easier to using something which already works than trying to build something by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats as follows:

```css
.friend_left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    clear: left;
}
.friend_right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    clear: right;
}
```

You need to account for unequal number of left and right floats, so you need to clear the left for `.friend-left` and the clear the right for `.friend_right`.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ESL5w/